# Getting "An item with this key has already been added" when performing a DeleteByQuery with Nest (Elasticsearch)

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to run a delete query to delete documents between two timestamps in an index, and I am getting a very strange result.

Here is my code:

```
// how the index is created
if (!es.IndexExists(indexName).Exists)
{
    es.CreateIndex(descriptor => descriptor
        .Index(indexName)
        .AddMapping<MyDocument>(m => m
            .MapFromAttributes()));
}

// event object that is mapped
public class MyDocument
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public long EventTime { get; set; }

    [ElasticProperty(Index = FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)]
    public string EventType { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<string, object> Values { get; set; }
    // snip
}

// delete call
IElasticClient es;
es.DeleteByQuery<MyDocument>(q => q
    .Query(rq => rq
        .Range(t => t.OnField("eventTime").GreaterOrEquals(startTimestamp).LowerOrEquals(endTimestamp)));
```

This throws an exception saying "An item with the same key has already been added".  What am I doing wrong with this delete query that would throw this exception?

Here is a sample document from a search I did through elasticsearch:

```
{
  "took" : 8,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 96,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "testing2",
      "_type" : "mydocument",
      "_id" : "112",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"id":112,"eventTime":12345690,"eventDate":"1970-05-23T17:21:30-04:00","eventTypeId":0,"ready":false,"name":"","doccount":0,"wordcount":0,"createdAt":"2015-06-25T09:29:33.8996707-04:00","values":{"internal_timestamp":76890.0},"childDocuments":[],"parentDocuments":[]}
    }, /* snip */]
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of NEST do you use?

Comment: May you share mapping for `eventTime` field? `startTimestamp` and `endTimestamp` is of type?

Comment: @Rob I've added my code for creating the index, as well as my code for mapping the object.  `startTimestamp` and `endTimestamp` are both `long`s, which maps to `EventTime` in my C# object

Comment: hmm ... still can't reproduce the issue(tested against NEST 1.5.1 and ES 1.5.2). It's possible to post sample documents? I can share my small example, so maybe it will put some light on it.

Comment: @Rob I've included a sample document from a search I performed against ES.  There are a few extra fields that I originally omitted from the doc to keep the length down

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81568/discussion-between-rob-and-jim).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rob and I just worked this out.

The problem that was occurring here is that my project is using `Newtonsoft.Json` version `7.0.0` with Nest version `1.5.1`, whereas Nest `1.5.1` requires `6.0.1`.  This mismatch was causing the serialization of queries to throw exceptions.

This can be solved by either upgrading Nest to version `1.6.1` or downgrading `Newtonsoft.Json` to version `6.0.1`.

Comment: Thank you so much!  You have saved me hours (if not days) by posting this answer!

Answer (score 1):

I've simply updated newtonsoft.json to latest version. My current version was 5.0.1, I've updated to 9.0.1. After that, error went away.